# How to get a list of all implemented classes in Strategy Pattern?

Tags: java, uml, strategy-pattern

I want to design a system that allows the user to select from a list of file types to save the file as. I have a class named Word, and an interface named SaveFileType. Every filetype implements SaveFileType which has a saveFile() method. The idea is that when the 'programmer' wants to add a new filetype, none of the code in the application has to be changed.

This is the UML diagram I have made: [image: UML Diagram]

The problem that I am facing is the Word class doesn't have the list of all available file types, that I need to display to the user.

Some sample code below:

Word class:

```
public class Word {
    SaveFileAs saveFileAs;
    Document currentDocument;

    public Word(Document currentDocument) {
        this.currentDocument = currentDocument;
    }

    public void saveFile() {
        // Print all available filetypes
        // No actual file-saving logic is needed.
    }
}
```

Word97 Class:

```
public class Word97 implements  SaveFileAs {
    @Override
    public void saveFile(Document currentDocument) {
        // Do some Java wizardry here.
        System.out.println("Document named '" + currentDocument.getTitle() + "' has been saved as filetype 'Word97' " );
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document notes = new Document("Notes", "This is a note.");
        Word wordProgram = new Word(notes);

        // saveFile should print out a list of all possible filetypes.
        wordProgram.saveFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: @fabian thank you for replying to my question. Bit harsh there, I'm quite new to all of this. I have changed the UML according to your feedback. Is 'FileType' a better name? If not, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Is this a UML or a implementation question, since I see only implementation answers?

Answer (score 0):

It would be bad if the `Word` class knew about all the types. It's the job of another class, even if word uses it. One solution would be to have a new class that maps a string extension to the strategy. And can enumerate those strategies:

```
public final class DocumentTypeMap implements Iterable<SaveFileAs> {
    private final Map<String, SaveFileAs> docTypes = new HashMap<>;

    public void register(String extension, SaveFileAs saveFileAs) {
        docTypes.put(extension, saveFileAs);
    }

    public Iterator<SaveFileAs> iterator() {
        return docTypes.values().iterator();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DocumentTypeMap map = new DocumentTypeMap();
map.register(".doc", new Word97()); //etc.
Word word = new Word(map); //inject the dependency of a pre-configured map into the word class.
```

Then when the `Word` class needs the correct strategy during saving, it can use a method on `DocumentTypeMap` (not provided here) to get the correct one. I'm thinking that might be by extension.

Comment: @cake Was this any help to you? Please upvote or accept helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy is for changing implementation at runtime, you cannot get all implementations. It would be the task of another class. Also you need somehow a method like `setStrategy(Strategy)` in your `Word` class, that's why you've chosen the pattern right?

For get all implementations, you could make use of `ServiceLoader`. I would add an enum in the picture.

So the example codes look like:

method in `Word` class:

```
void setSaveFileStrategy(AvailableStrategy strategy){
    this.saveFileAs = strategy.strategy();
}
```

The enum:

```
enum AvailableStrategy{
        Word97( Word97.class),
        //.... once new strategy was introduced, you need add an entry here.
        WordXml( WordXml.class);

        private Class<saveFileAs> strategyClass;

        AvailableStrategies(Class<saveFileAs> strategyClass) {
            this.strategyClass = strategyClass;
        }

        saveFileAs strategy() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
           return strategyClass.newInstance() ;
        }

    }
```

I think you know how to get all enum instances (available strategies).

Note that codes were not compiled and tested, just for showing the idea. Exception handlings were ignored.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply. This seems like the most elegant solution posted here. However, I must be able to add additional filetypes without changing any of the code in the system. Maybe the strategy pattern isn't the solution here?

Comment: why "without changing any of codes"? you have to recompile anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to add a document type without changing any code, it means that the document type list has to be defined outside your code, in file like a property file and your code has to read the property file to know all available types.

Then you need to add in this property file which class implements how to save a specific document type and you implement a factory which instantiate a class given its name, and a class which associate the right instance according to the chosen type.

For the properties files, you can have entries like:

ext_1=.doc

ext_2=.xml

ext_3=.rtf

class_1=Word97

class_2=WordXML

class_3=RTF ...

A such file is easy to parse to know the types list and which class has to be used to save a document.
To know how to instantiate a class from its name, see the class `Class` and the method `newInstance`.

This is an "old way", maybe with injection is there a most up to date solution.

In your UML model, I would add the class which reads the properties file, the class which instantiates a class from its name, and the class which associate the right instance to Word. To model the properties file, maybe an instance objet may be use since a properties file is an instance of ResourceBundle.